# Gitlab Slack Integration question (about Pipelines)

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline, slack

After integration I'm receiving next messages:[image]

I'd really like to customize it if the pipeline fails like:

1. Test #1 passed
2. Test #2 passed
3. Test #3 failed....

Is it possible to do? I have seen an example of it from Testim.io pipelines it was looking so and it was perfect and understandable for everyone where is the problem (i mean the client etc)